# Shrinkwrap modifier issue with retopology

Tags: modifiers, topology

[image]

I started to do retopology for a character, and there is a weird issue when I try and connect things together. I have the clipping option turned on for the Mirror modifier, but the two sides don't always clip at the middle.

[image]

I thought it might be a problem with the Mirror modifier at first, but it seems to be the Shrinkwrap modifier that cause the issue. When I turned the Shrinkwrap, the clipping works fine.

[image]

Does anyone know what can cause it, and how to fix the issue?

Comment: Could you please embed your images directly in your post? For that, use the `Edit` link then the `Add image` icon (Ctrl-G). Thx

Comment: Sure. Edited it.